# Tables with names inside tables

Tags: function, lua, terminal, arguments, love2d

So I have created a Lua program to keep track of the needs of a property my father is buying, and I want to make tables inside tables WITH NAMES. So when I try to add it through a function I created, (I'll show the function), it expects `)` where "=" is.

```
--The table I'm using to store everything
repair={}
--The function I'm using to create tables inside tables
function rAdd(name)
 table.insert(repair, name)
end
--The function I'm using to add data to those tables
function tAdd(table, name)
 table.insert(table, name)
end
rAdd(wall={})
tAdd(wall, "Due for paint job")
```

And when I try to add it (`rAdd(wall={})`) it expects me to end the argument via `)` at the "=". Please help!

Comment: You can't assign a value to a variable *in* a function call. What are you trying to actually do there? Are you trying to nest tables? `t = {f = {}}`? Otherwise is `wall={}; `rAdd("wall")` what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mocking around with `table.insert`, just use the fact Lua tables can be accessed like, well tables:

```
repair["wall"] = {}
```

Now you can actually insert into it:

```
table.insert(repair["wall"], "Due for a paint job")
```

If you want to hide the global variable behind a function:

```
function rAdd(name, value)
    repair[name] = value
end

rAdd("wall", {});
```

Or if you really want to pass entries in the table form:

```
function rAddN(entries)
    for k,v in pairs(entries) do
        repair[k] = v
    end
end

rAddN({ wall = {} })
```

Note that you can omit parens in this case:

```
rAddN { wall = {} }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But... I ran into another problem. Whenever I had table.insert, it would think of it as a nil value. This has happened in the past, and I'm thinking it's a syntax error of some sort, do you have an explanation?